# connect_error returns nothing, but code not working

Tags: php, mysql

It always returns empty `connect_error` value. It connects to mySQL properly. I want to create simple registering system on my page. I'm new to PHP and HTML, so I don't know what is wrong in this code. MySQL works properly, I think, so maybe something is wrong with my SQL code?

This is my PHP code:

```
<?php
$link = @new mysqli('valid localhost', 'valid user', 'valid password', 'valid database');
if ($link->connect_error!=0) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . $link->connect_error); 
}

$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$confirm = $_POST['confirmpassword'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$result = mysql_query($sql, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_rows FROM `users` WHERE username='{$login}' LIMIT 1;");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql, $result);
if($row["num_rows"] < 0){
    header('Location: index.php');
    return;
}

if($password != $confirm) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    return;
}


$login = htmlentities($login, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
$password = htmlentities($password, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
$email = htmlentities($email, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");

$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, `email`) VALUES
('%s', '%s', '%s');",
mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $login),
mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $password),
mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $email));
if (mysql_query($sql, $link)) {
    echo "User created successfully!\n";
} else {
    echo 'Error creating user: ' . $link->connect_error . "\n";
}
?>
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <title>Awesome title</title>
</head>

<body>

    Register<br /><br />

    <form action="register.php" method="post">

        Login: <br /> <input type="text" name="login" /> <br />
        Email: <br /> <input type="email" name="email" /> <br />
        Password: <br /> <input type="password" name="password" /> <br />
        Confirm password: <br /> <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" /> <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Register" />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and MySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `username` text collate utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` text collate utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` text collate utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci;
```

This is what I get:

> Error creating user:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

`echo 'Error creating user: ' . $link->connect_error . "\n";`

to

`echo 'Error creating user: ' . $link->error . "\n";`

Also, you're mixing mysql and mysqli, and mixing object oriented with procedural.

Try this:

```
<?php
$link = @new mysqli('valid localhost', 'valid user', 'valid password', 'valid database');
if ($link->connect_error) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . $link->connect_error); 
}

$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$confirm = $_POST['confirmpassword'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$result = $link->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_rows FROM `users` WHERE username='{$login}' LIMIT 1;");
$row = $result->fetch();
if($result->num_rows < 0){
    header('Location: index.php');
    return;
}

if($password != $confirm) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    return;
}


$login = htmlentities($login, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
$password = htmlentities($password, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
$email = htmlentities($email, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");

$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, `email`) VALUES
('%s', '%s', '%s');",
$link->real_escape_string($login),
$link->real_escape_string($password),
$link->real_escape_string($email));
if ($link->query($sql)) {
    echo "User created successfully!\n";
} else {
    echo 'Error creating user: ' . $result->error . "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Same as before, `Error creating user: `

Comment: @xVacuum - I'll be happy to help you further if you can show me I'm not wasting my time by giving me an upvote.

Comment: I can't my friend.   `Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score.`

Comment: @xVacuum - Ok, but I hope you'll hit the chcekmark if I solve your problem. Question: is this your working code or did you change it to remove your creds from StackOverflow: `$link = @new mysqli('valid localhost', 'valid user', 'valid password', 'valid database');`

Comment: Okey, no problem. My answer is: no.

Comment: @xVacuum - Please remove that comment I was just looking for a yes or no answer, you don't want to put your live credentials on a public website. that's how you get hacked. Hang on one sec I'll update my answer.

Comment: Looks really good, but returns `Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch() in register.php on line 13`   line 13 contains `$row = $result->fetch();`

Comment: @xVacuum woops change fetch to fetch_array

Comment: Use this $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

Comment: This script is open to SQL-injection, you should've used prepared statements.

Comment: @Qirel - only the first one is open to injection. He's escapting the second one. No need for prepared statemnt, but i agree that he should escape the first one as well.

Comment: @Pamblam - it's usually enough, but usage of prepared statements is the only real way to go (at least my opinion, and if you Google around on SQL-injection, most answers are that prepared statements > escaping).

Comment: @Qirel - you've gotta take this stuff on a case by case basis. you're right prepared > escape but in *this situation* escape will suit him fine.

Comment: @Pamblam one more question, i can only create 1 user, because if i create more users, code will back me to index.php :/

Comment: @xVacuum - you're using a different username each time, right?

Comment: also, change the first query to begin like this... `SELECT username FROM ...`

Answer (score 0):

This code is causing you some trouble. First of all, you are mixing APIs. Here with `mysql_*` (which is deprecated), while your connection is OOP MySQLi (you *cannot* mix MySQL APIs).

```
if (mysql_query($sql, $link)) {
    echo "User created successfully!\n";
} else {
    echo 'Error creating user: ' . $link->connect_error . "\n";
}
```

You should have something like this instead, sticking **purely** with one style: as I recommend (which you started doing) with OOP MySQLi.

```
if ($link->query($sql)) {
    echo "User created successfully!\n";
} else {
    echo 'Error creating user: ' . $link->connect_error . "\n";
}
```

---

This code is kind of poorly written. It makes your SQL query being broken.

```
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `password`, `email`) VALUES
('%s', '%s', '%s');",
mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $login),
mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $password),
mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $email));
```

It seems like you are trying to prevent SQL-injection? May I suggest usage of prepared statements instead? This is the modern standard, and looks better.

```
if (!$stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)")) {
    // Something went wrnog, here handle it
    return false;
}
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $login, $password, $email)
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

In the `pind_param` the first parameter is `sss` - this stands for *string, string, string* - as your `$login, $password, $email` are all strings. Note that this number must match the number of question-marks in `prepare`. You should also do the same for your first query, where you select

Comment: Thanks for tips! I will use them in future <3

Comment: You really should convert to using prepared statements right away, else your script is open to a huge security risk.

Comment: Yes, i know. One more question, in VALUES i must add 's, s, s'? I dont understand this part of your code :P

Comment: The `prepare` holds the SQL-statement, where the question-marks are being replaced by whatever is inside `bind_param`, so if you have 3 columns in your database, that's 3 question-marks in the `prepare`-statement, `sss` (three strings) in the first parameter of `bind_param` and the three variables that will be inserted as the rest.

Comment: not only will that always eval to true, it will overwrite your mysqli query

Comment: Well, thanks for pointing it out, a simple typo... Happens to all of us from time to other. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
if (mysql_query($sql, $link)) {
    echo "User created successfully!\n";
} else {
    echo 'Error creating user: ' . $link->connect_error . "\n";
}
```

to

```
if ($link->query($sql)) {
    printf("User created successfully!\n");
}
```

This should work for you.